# Saving a form after filled in Android

Tags: android, user-interface

I wanted to know how to create something like this to save information, after a form has been filled out? This is from the App Timetable and I couldnt get any information on how to do this? Any Suggestions/Solutions?

[image: androidscreenshot]

Regards,

Michael

Answer (score 0):

Refer this [information](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) on Android Developers website for Storage Options in Android.

You will read if you need to store large amount of data you need to create a Sqlite Database but if you need to save small amount of data then Shared Preferences will do.

Now you need to save and retrieve data from these storage options.

1) [Shared Preferences Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidFileBasedPersistence/article.html)

2) [Sqlite Database Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html)

I assume till now you have done with saving and retrieving data . Now you need to match your current time with saved time in your app like a Alarm clock do. For that you need to implement a service that will tell you how much time is left in your task or what is upcoming event.

[Tutorial on service.](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html)

Comment: This is merely a custom dialog.